# Oracle sql query help needed

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query that should do the following :

Three entities are involved lets say `A,B,C` and I have to find the list of C such that

```
sum(C.noOfOrders) < B.maxNoOfOrders where A.BID = B.ID and B.ID = C.BID and A.RunId = C.RunId
```

Note : `sum(C.noOfOrders)` means sum of noOfOrders from the result of C should be less than B.maxNoOfOrders.

Please suggest me the query with explanation.

Example data below :

#### A

```
ID  | RunId | BID
------------------
100 | 1001 | 100 
200 | 1002 | 200
300 | 1003 | 300
400 | 1004 | 400
```

#### B

```
ID    |  maxNoOfOrders
-----------------------
100 | 50    
200 | 10
300 | 50
400 | 15
```

#### C

```
  Id | RunId |  BID |  noOfOrders
-----------------------------------
 101 | 1001  | 100  |  10
 102 | 1001  | 100  |  10
 103 | 1003  | 200  |  20 
 104 | 1004  | 300  |  50
 200 | 1001  | 100  |  10
 201 | 2002  | 100  |  10
 300 | 3001  | 200  |  50
 401 | 4001  | 300  |   5
 402 | 4002  | 400  |  10
```

This should return list of C with ID 101,102 and 200 because (10 + 10 + 10) < 50

Comment: Perhaps some table names, fields and sample data will help explain this better

Comment: OK I added example data as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  `GROUP BY`and `HAVING` clauses:

```
   SELECT C.Id
     FROM C
     JOIN B ON B.ID = C.BID
     JOIN A ON A.BID = B.ID AND A.RunId = C.RunId
 GROUP BY C.Id
   HAVING sum(C.noOfOrders) < B.maxNoOfOrders
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Could you post your REAL query?

Comment: This error means that you have got some field in the `SELECT` clause that is not in the `GROUP BY` clause. Every field you're selecting must be a `GROUP BY` field OR the result of an aggregate function.

Comment: Only difference in your query than mine is below :
HAVING SUM(EXTRACTVALUE(C.details, '/C/NbOfOrds')) < EXTRACTVALUE(B.details,'/B/maxNoOfOrders')

Comment: As stated on http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00979.php , ORA-00979 is due to having an expression in the `SELECT`clause that is not an aggregate function and is not on the `GROUP BY` clause. Could you try to execute my query exactly as it is?